# How can I compile imgcnv?

Tags: software-installation, compiling

I'd like to compile [imgcnv](http://biodev.ece.ucsb.edu/projects/bioimage/downloader/download/category/4) so that I can chop up images for [panojs](http://www.dimin.net/software/panojs/#Demos).  `imgcnv`'s INSTALL directions are extremely curt:

```
$ pwd
/home/$USER/src/imgcnv
$ ls
build-imgcnv-cygwin.sh  INSTALL      matlab     msvc2010_bimread   src_bimread
build-imgcnv-linux.sh   libs         msvc2008       msvc2010_gobjects  src_gobjects
build-imgcnv-macosx.sh  libsrc       msvc2008_bimread   readme.txt     testing
changelog.txt       LICENCE.txt  msvc2008_gobjects  scripts
generated       Makefile     msvc2010       src
$ cat INSTALL 
Welcome to imgcnv.  A utlity for reading and converting 
biological image formats.
1.  To install just execute,
    $ make install
2.  Sit back
```

I downloaded a fresh 1.52 directory.

I've already got the latest qt4-make, but I can't successfully make:

```
$ make
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lbz2
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [../imgcnv] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/$USER/src/imgcnv/src'
#(cd src; qmake imgcnv.pro)
#(cd src; make)
```

I'm on 32-bit Oneiric on an intel machine (hp 6220 laptop)

Comment: do `sh ./build-imgcnv-linux.sh`. you can test if it works by typing `./imgcnv -fmt`. for installing it pemanently u could try reading the readme.txt or install.if my soln works tell me ill post it as an ans.

Comment: When I run build-imgcnv-linux.sh it ends with a bunch of errors and make install still doesn't work.  Thanks for your help so far!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short answer (applies to your specific situation)

1. Install the `qt4-qmake` package (or if that's unavailable, the `qt3-dev-tools` package). Also install the `libbz2-dev` package. (You can install both from the command-line by running `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get install qt4-qmake libbz2-dev`.)
2. If you don't want `imgcnv` installed in `/usr/bin` (which is the default location), edit `Makefile` and change the first line (which reads `prefix=/usr`). For example, if you want it in `/usr/local/bin`, which is the normal place for software you build and install from source (and not through Ubuntu's package manager), make this line say `prefix=/usr/local`. If you want to install `imgcnv` in your home directory, then create `$HOME/bin` if it doesn't already exist and edit `Makefile`'s first line to read `$HOME`.
3. Run `make`.
4. Run `sudo make install` (unless you're installing in your home directory; then run `make install`).
5. Assuming that worked, it's pretty clear the official installation instructions are faulty, so optionally, you may want to report this as a bug to imgcnv's maintainers.

This worked for me to build [imgcnv 1.52](http://biodev.ece.ucsb.edu/projects/bioimage/downloader/download/category/4/file/234) on an Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric Ocelot amd64 (i.e., 64-bit) system. If it doesn't work for you, please comment with details (including error messages and the version and architecture of your Ubuntu system).

If it doesn't work for you, you might try deleting your `imgcnv` folder and starting over, re-extracting the archive. Perhaps running the script manually, as you have done, has messed up something that prevented `make` from working.

### Longer answer (applies also to similar situations)

The standard way to build software from source that has good instructions that work is to follow them. Unfortunately this doesn't.

The standard way to build software from source without instructions (or with non-working instructions) is to see if there is a script called `configure`. If there is, run `./configure --help` to see what kind of command-line options it takes. Then run the script, with whatever options are appropriate for your needs. Often you may run `./configure` with no options, as the defaults are often acceptable. After running `./configure`, you may be given instructions. If you are told to run `make`, or if you are not given instructions, you should then run `make`.

If there is no `configure` script (as is the case here), see if there is a file called `Makefile`. If there is, then run `make`. (When there is a `configure` script, this script will often generate the `Makefile`, or on rare occasion may modify it.) You may first want to edit `Makefile` to customize options for building or installing. One purpose of a `configure` script is to render this unnecessary by creating a `Makefile` that is customized according to your specifications. One of the most commonly customized variables in a makefile is `prefix`, which controls where the software will be installed. (See the "Short answer" above for a specific example of this.)

Running `./configure` or `make` will sometimes fail, telling you that you don't have something you need. When that happens, you must install that thing. When I ran `make`, everything seemed to be going well until it eventually failed because the `qmake` command was not present on my system. Since `qmake` is a command, I tried to run it manually, which gave me a detailed message telling me I didn't have it (which I already knew) and what packages I could install to get it. Then I installed one of those packages (`qt4-qmake`) and ran `make` again. (If it had been a library or header files, I might have needed to search at http://packages.ubuntu.com to see what provides it.)

Running `make` again will often be able to pick up where it left off (or even if not, then from somewhere later than the beginning). Some software--including imgcnv--can take quite some time to build, so it's a good idea to try to pick up where you left off. Occasionally this causes problems though, so if you run `make` again and it fails, you can run `make distclean` to bring things back to the way they were before you ran `make`, then run `make`. (If `make distclean` doesn't work, run `make clean`.)

Sometimes a source distribution has build scripts, like `build-imgcnv-linux.sh` in imgcnv. If there are both build scripts and a `Makefile`, and the documentation doesn't tell you to run a build script manually, it's advisable to try running `make` first, especially if the instructions tell you to run `make install`. In a properly set up source distribution that has a `Makefile`, running `make install` would do the same thing as running `make` followed by `make install` (i.e., it would see that the software hadn't been built yet, and it would build it before attempting to install it). But sometimes that doesn't work, so then you have to run `make` first.

It's advisable to run `make` before `make install` anyway, even if you know running `make install` by itself would take care of the `make` step automatically. There are three reasons for this:

1. If anything happens during the `make` step that causes you alarm (even if it isn't an error), you're not installing software that might not be built the way you want it. For example, there could be warnings advising you of potential problems.
2. This doesn't apply to `imgcnv`. But many source distributions come with testsuites to see if the built program is likely to work properly. You can build and run them with either `make check` or `make test`. (If the documentation doesn't say anything about them, I recommend trying those commands in that order.) These don't get run automatically by running `make install`, and while you might be able to just run `make check` or `make test` without running `make` first, that's undesirable because it might not be clear if an error happened while building the software or while building/running the testsuite (which is crucial information for troubleshooting the problem).
3. If you're installing the software for the whole system (rather than just your user), which is almost always the default configuration, then `make install` needs to be run as `root`. On Ubuntu, the proper way to do this is by running `sudo make install` instead of `make install`. But you don't need to actually build the software as `root`, so you can build the software as yourself with `make` and then install it as `root` with `sudo make install`.

If you're sure you want to both build and install (no matter what kind of scary warnings come out of building) and `make install` doesn't work, you can use the idiom `make && make install`. This also addresses the `root`/non-`root` issue, as you can run `make && sudo make install`. The `&&` operator, used in this way, causes the command to the right of it to run only if the command to the left of it seems to have succeeded.

(I've intentionally left out discussion of how to build software that requires the user to invoke `autoconf`, `automake`, and/or an `autogen.sh` script, as source code of stable releases very rarely requires this. However, if someone wants to edit this post an add instructions covering those situations, under a third subject heading, I would have no objection.)

Comment: I downloaded a fresh 1.52 directory.

I've already got the latest qt4-make, but I can't succesfully make:

    $ make
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lbz2
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    make[1]: *** [../imgcnv] Error 1
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/$USER/src/imgcnv/src'
    #(cd src; qmake imgcnv.pro)
    #(cd src; make)

I'm on 32-bit Oneiric on an intel machine (hp 6220 laptop)

Comment: @JohnBaber It's hard for me to interpret that error message as you have not indicated where one line ends and another begins. If that's the complete output of `make`, then please edit your question to include it (then you can comment here to let me know you've done so). If there was a lot of output and that's just the end, then you can select all the text in the Terminal, paste it at http://paste.ubuntu.com, and comment with a link.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that comments can't show code formatting.  [Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/941575/) is the pastebin of what happens when I try to make.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JohnBaber Install `libbz2-dev` and try again. (My system already had that, so I never got your error.) In general, when you get `cannot find -lX`, where `X` is some sequence of characters, search for an Ubuntu package named something like `libX-dev` (sometimes there will be numbers in the package name too, though). BTW I'm editing my answer to add information about how `libbz2-dev` is needed. (And comments do support code formatting, but only the simple kind where you put code between a pair of tickmarks--i.e., "lower case tilde"--which is what I'm using in this comment.)

Comment: That seems to have done it.  It compiles fine now, thank you.  I can rewrite my question so I just `cat INSTALL` and link to the pastebin.  Then you can have the top of your response be "get `libbz2-dev` and `qt4make`" and I'll checkmark it as the true answer.

Comment: @JohnBaber I think my answer, in its current form, would likely be useful to others with similar problems with other software. Furthermore, your original error messages indicate that is very unlikely that it would have worked, had installing `libbz2-dev` first been the only thing you had done differently. Or are you saying that were you actually able to delete the `imgcnv` source folder, unpack the archive again, and, with `libbz2-dev` installed, build and install imgcnv just by running `make install`?

Comment: I see what you mean, I just meant add libbz2 to the list of things I'd done wrong.  Your answer is what would have worked from the beginning.  I didn't remove the directory again from scratch before running make.  All I did was go back in after installing libbz2-dev and `make`d again and it worked.  Thanks again!